# React.js - can't update form that is based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a basic thing: insert data, which gets passed back to the main component, and display a list of items, that can be clicked and edited in the form.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
  class SimpleForm extends React.Component {

      constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
              id: null,
              firstName: ''
          };
      }

      static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
          if (props.user === null) return null;

          return {
              id: props.user.id,
              firstName: props.user.firstName
          }
      }


      handleChange = e => {
          const value = e.target.value;
          this.setState(prevState => {
              return {
                  firstName: value
              }
          });
      }

      handleSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const event = e.target;
          this.props.onAdd(this.state);

          this.setState(prevState => {
              return {
                  id: null,
                  firstName: ''
              };
          }, () => {
              event.reset();
          });
      }

      render() {
          const {
              firstName
          } = this.state;
          return ( <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
              <input type = "text"
                  name = "firstName"
                  value = {firstName}
                  onChange = {this.handleChange} /> &nbsp; 
              <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
              </form>
          );
      }
  }
```

Here's the example: http://jsbin.com/yawasoz/1/edit?html,js,output

If you insert one item and then click on the "LI" element, you'll see that the state in the form gets set properly. However, you can't edit the data at all in the input - when I'm typing, the text stays the same. Much like if the "onChange" method didn't exist. What's going on here? I think that I might be using "getDerivedStateFromProps" incorrectly?

Comment: The reason you cannot edit it is because once you click an entry it pins the value of this.state.firstName to props.user.firstName; this is an issue of logic.

Comment: So what would be the correct approach to setting a value to a state, as in my case?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, this is a bug (as stated here https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8mslha/cant_update_form_that_is_based_on_state/dzq4zen) in the latest version of React, downgrading to 16.3 works as intended: http://jsbin.com/wilahihuyu/1/edit

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Based on the discussion on github, this is NOT a bug, the bug was in the code and the version 16.4 made it apparent. Here's the discussion: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12898#issuecomment-392035163